# Override DeviseController base class - Rails 4, Devise 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am trying to override the Devise method [`set_flash_message`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise_controller.rb#L145). Devise documentation covers how to [override controllers for the various submodules](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers).

However this particular method is located within [`DeviseController`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise_controller.rb), the **parent** class of all the modules.

The documentation (both wiki and inline) says nothing about how to achieve this, so I'm not sure how best to proceed. I believe the best approach would be to simply re-open the class and modify the method as needed, and I placed a file in `/lib` to that effect. However it appears that is getting loaded prior to Devise, resulting in error spew.

```
NameError in Devise::RegistrationsController#new
undefined local variable or method `require_no_authentication' for #<Devise::RegistrationsController>
```

The complex parent definition for `DeviseController` may also be having an net negative effect:

```
class DeviseController < Devise.parent_controller.constantize
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just override the function definition in your controller?

Comment: There is no "my" controller, Devise provides the controllers for you. You can override them (see second link above), but that only applies to the subclasses representing Devise's modules.

Comment: Unless you want to fork Devise, you are going to have to make your own controllers and override the method.

Comment: @Justin - Looking for clarification: are you suggesting that I instantiate an overriding class for every Devise module, since I am trying to override a method in the parent class?

I know, see my comments about re-opening the DeviseController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is the syntax to override Devise controllers:

```
class RegistrationsController <  Devise::RegistrationsController
```

If you're receiving method errors, you need to remember this won't totally overwrite the controller - your methods will be delegated to from the "main" devise controller, so you can use things like this:

```
def method
    super
    your_code_here
end
```

**Update**

```
class SessionsController < DeviseController
  prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication, :only => [ :new, :create ]
  prepend_before_filter :allow_params_authentication!, :only => :create
  prepend_before_filter { request.env["devise.skip_timeout"] = true }

  prepend_view_path 'app/views/devise'

  # GET /resource/sign_in
  def new
    self.resource = resource_class.new(sign_in_params)
    clean_up_passwords(resource)
    respond_with(resource, serialize_options(resource))
  end

  # POST /resource/sign_in
  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)

    respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render :json => {}, :status => :ok }
        format.html { respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource) } 
    end
  end

  # DELETE /resource/sign_out
  def destroy
    redirect_path = after_sign_out_path_for(resource_name)
    signed_out = (Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(resource_name))
    set_flash_message :notice, :signed_out if signed_out && is_navigational_format?

    # We actually need to hardcode this as Rails default responder doesn't
    # support returning empty response on GET request
    respond_to do |format|
      format.all { head :no_content }
      format.any(*navigational_formats) { redirect_to redirect_path }
    end
  end


  protected

  def sign_in_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:sign_in)
  end

  def serialize_options(resource)
    methods = resource_class.authentication_keys.dup
    methods = methods.keys if methods.is_a?(Hash)
    methods << :password if resource.respond_to?(:password)
    { :methods => methods, :only => [:password] }
  end

  def auth_options
    { :scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#new" }
  end
end
```

Comment: We have successfully overridden the Devise controllers multiple times btw :)

Comment: As have I, however I'm not overriding the Devise controllers, but the PARENT of those controllers. Show me an example that instantiates like this: `class CustomController > DeviseController`. Note the name of the parent class. I don't want/need to override `RegistrationsController`, or `SessionsController`, or `ConfirmationsController`, etc.

Comment: Posted an update from one of our older apps. Probably won't work, but will be interesting to see what happens!

Comment: Yeah sorry, not what I need. Ever do anything that directly affected `DeviseController`?

Answer (score 1):

`Devise.parent_controller` is defined in the Devise module definition in `devise/devise.rb`. [Luckily, it has `mattr_accessor` declared](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/9a11586a724487dc98dddea0ab9c8afcc0e9439d/lib/devise.rb#L226), so you can set the value yourself (the default value is "ApplicationController"). It probably makes the most sense to do this some time in your application initialization process, for example, along with the rest of the Devise configuration in `initializers/devise.rb`.

Answer (score 1):

I made the file:

```
config/initilializers/devise_controller.rb
```

and put:

```
DeviseController.class_eval do
  protected

  def set_flash_message
    ....
  end

  def resource_params
    ....
  end
end
```

That seemed to do the trick. I was concerned about load order, and at least class_eval will give you an error if the class doesn't already exist, instead of silently overwriting it.

Comment: Works for me using Rails 5. Added it at the end of the existing `config/initilializers/devise.rb`.

Answer (score 0):

I only needed to override `find_message` and `set_flash_messages` in one particular controller (`RegistrationsController`).

To override/append to the method, I just ended up writing the method in the RegistrationsController itself. This could be extracted to a module and used in multiple Devise Controllers, giving a single location to the modified method.

This way, I was able to use `super` as well. I had some difficulties using `super` with `class_eval`...

My controller looks like this now:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  ###

  protected 

  def find_message(kind, options = {})
    # my custom code here
    super
  end
end
```