# Extend base DeviseController class with method for callbacks in SessionsController and RegistrationsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, callback, controller

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21769980/override-devisecontroller-base-class-rails-4-devise-3), which doesn't have an answer.

I want to add `after_filter :identify_with_segment, only: [:create]` to both my `RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController` and `SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController`. Since both of these controllers themselves inherit from `DeviseController`, I thought that a DRY way to do this would be to extend `DeviseController` and define the method there. However, I keep getting an `unitialized constant` error.

My code:

```
class DeviseController < DeviseController
  def identify_with_segment
    ..
  end
end
```

I realize the way this class is defined just looks wrong. I've also tried `class DeviseController < Devise::DeviseController` but that doesn't work either.

Can anyone explain the proper way to extend the `DeviseController` that these other controllers depend on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to open `DeviseController`, you can just try this:

```
class DeviseController
   def identify_with_segment
     # ...
   end
end
```

Lots of confusing things are done in the name of strict DRY-ness, this may be one of those things.  Sometimes repeating yourself makes things clear and understandable for the human that comes after you.

Another option would be to put this functionality into a concern, and `include` that module in your `RegistrationsController` and `SessionsController`.  Then it's explicit what you're doing and you aren't modifying classes that you don't own.  Something like:

```
# app/controllers/concerns/whatever_it_is_this_is_doing.rb
module WhateverItIsThisIsDoing

  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def identify_with_segment
    # ...
  end

  included do
    after_filter :identify_with_segment, only: [:create]
  end

end

# app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb
class RegistrationsController
  include WhateverItIsThisIsDoing
end

# app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb
class SessionsController
  include WhateverItIsThisIsDoing
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up going with a similar solution of making `identify_with_segment` a protected method in ApplicationController so it would be available that way. Marking this answer correct though as it addresses the concept and provides a good solution. Do you see any issue with what I went with?

Comment: I've seen ApplicationController become a dumping ground for unrelated stuff like that. Just be sure to refactor if it starts to get that way!

Comment: I agree with @NickVeys "Lots of confusing things are done in the name of strict DRY-ness... Sometimes repeating yourself makes things clear and understandable for the human that comes after you." In a similar situation, I found it was easier and clearer to simply [customise each controller](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers) with the inclusion of an `ActiveSupport::Concern` rather than try to reopen `DeviseController`.